# What are cons to use % over em in terms of accessibility?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, accessibility

What are cons to use % over em in terms of accessibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there are any any more.

In the olden days, internet explorer wouldn't let you zoom a page if sizes were specified in pixels, but would if in em or %. This led to the recommendation to stay away from pixels in order to allow users to view content at a size useful for them.

Nowadays, all modern browsers do a full page zoom, irrespective of what units you use to size things in, so basically it's up to you.

I often use pixels when things need to be perfectly lined up, and em when sizing fonts and paragraph margins etc to keep a vertical rhythm.

Comment: actually here it says % are prefered http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssfonts/, however I've been  using em's for years and only now ran into this discussion after switching to HTML5 Boilerplate CSS reset

Answer (score 0):

% over em?

I would say no advantage concerning accessibility as far as I know, but I would say it is hard to switch from one to the other.

Isn't '%' a relational size, whereas 'em' is an absolute size? The one is for liquid layouts, the other isn't...

Comment: `em`s are relative too. 1 em = the width of an "M"

Comment: Well, yes and no...  Neither is absolute, but they're based on different things.  % is relative to the user's *window* size and em is relative to the user's *font* size.